# How do I remove the default UI pop ups from GoogleMaps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

The question is in the title: *How do I remove the default UI pop ups from GoogleMaps?*

Everything will become clear once you look at the screenshot below (PFA). Please tell me if there is more content I should add in this question (n00b).

I have to disable the pop ups on the bottom right.

[image: Photo]

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to remove the directions and map icons in the bottom right corner?

Comment: @buczek yes thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using something along these lines?

```
GoogleMap map;

UiSettings config = map.getUiSettings();
config.setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
config.setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

From my experience this is exactly what you need.

Comment: does this need to be in the onCreate method?

Comment: It should be wherever before you show the map. Dont forget to upvote good answers in addition to ticking it :)

Comment: Don't have enough rep :)

Comment: Actually I believe you can upvote regardless of rep :)